# GetQueuedCompletionStatus и тайм-аут

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, за что конкретно отвечает параметр dwMilliseconds в GetQueuedCompletionStatus ?

Да, я понимаю, что на MSDN все написано: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getqueuedcompletionstatus

> dwMilliseconds
>
> Количество миллисекунд, в течение которых вызывающий абонент готов
> ждать появления пакета завершения в порту завершения. Если пакет
> завершения не появляется в течение указанного времени, функция
> истекает по тайм-ауту , возвращает FALSE и устанавливает *
> lpOverlapped в NULL .
>
> Если dwMilliseconds является INFINITE , функция никогда не будет тайм
>
> - аут. Если dwMilliseconds равно нулю и нет операции ввода-вывода для удаления из очереди, функция немедленно истечет по тайм-ауту.

Но, вот вроде бы написано, а все равно, что хотели сообщить этим описанием не совсем понятно.

Это то время, которое проходит с момента вызова функции(на чтения/запись сокета, файла), которая помещает задачу в порт завершения и если в течении этих dwMilliseconds секунд с этого момента, оповещение о готовой задачи на чтение/запись не будет - то функция вернет задачу с сообщением о тайм-ауте ?
Это имеется ввиду ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports

Comment: @– こきん, ну это первое что я читал.